# Looking for the right algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

If I have a set of nodes with ids and pointers to other nodes like this:

```
1 -> 2
2 -> 4
2 -> 3
3 -> 4
5 -> 1
...
```

How can I display this graph in 2 dimensions (on an x-y plane)? Is there a way to project these 1d points into 2d? I'm looking looking for someone to point me to an algorithm that I can use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of 2D view do you want? Is there some particular property you want the 2D view to show off?

Comment: @templatetypedef I'm just looking to make all of the edges visible. If I keep them in 1-d, they will only look like one big edge connecting them all. This is why I need another dimension. The other details don't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [PolygonFactory.createPolygon](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/PolygonFactory.java)

You can then use the points in the Polygon return value and draw the connections you want.

Comment: The thing is that I want the nodes that are one step away to be next to each other. It looks like this just makes a shape out of the points that approaches a circle.

Comment: Like I said (or intended to say) rather than using the actual Polygon as a polygon, just use the points that are generated and draw your edges in a loop based on your data using Graphics.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2)

Comment: @Josh In the general case, this is geometrically impossible, without reducing every point to the same, single point... Imagine a fully connected network of 8 nodes. And unless you know something specific about the kind of connections your network is always going to have, there's no simple algorithm for this

Comment: Oh, I thought I remembered GNUPlot being about to do this. Maybe I'm thinking of similar functionality.